# How to use eosjs V20 to create and sign a offline actions？

Tags: cleos, eosjs, wallet, node, signing

when I create actions like this,and prapare to use JsSignatureProvider to sign

```
(async()=>{
  let actions = [{
    account: 'tommy',
    name: 'hi',
    authorization: [{
      actor: 'tommy',
      permission: 'active',
    }],
    data: {
      user: 'tommy'
    },
  }
  let seActions = await api.serializeActions(actions)   
  console.log(seActions)
})()

 let seActions =  api.serializeActions(tx) ;
 console.log(seActions);
```

but nodejs report this error:

```
TypeError: actions.map is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot to add the closing square bracket after your action. I assume this is the problem. It should instead look like this:

```
(async()=>{
  let actions = [{
    account: 'tommy',
    name: 'hi',
    authorization: [{
      actor: 'tommy',
      permission: 'active',
    }],
    data: {
      user: 'tommy'
    },
  }]
  let seActions = await api.serializeActions(actions)   
  console.log(seActions)
})()

 let seActions =  api.serializeActions(tx) ;
 console.log(seActions);
```